# Retrieve traditional Chinese entries from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, internationalization, china

I want to retrieve both simplified and traditional Chinese entries from OpenStreetMap. E.g.

```
<node id="244082315" lat="43.558611" lon="126.228611" version="5"     timestamp="2014-01-21T10:07:18Z" changeset="20119519" uid="274857" user="Supaplex">
<tag k="name" v="永吉县"/>
<tag k="place" v="suburb"/>
<tag k="gns:DSG" v="ADM3"/>
<tag k="gns:UFI" v="-1936843"/>
<tag k="gns:UNI" v="6771391"/>
<tag k="name:vi" v="Vĩnh Cát"/>
<tag k="name:zh" v="永吉县"/>
<tag k="gns:ADM1" v="05"/>
<tag k="name:zh_pinyin" v="Yongji Xian"/>
<tag k="name:zh-simplified" v="永吉县"/>
<tag k="name:zh-traditional" v="永吉縣"/>
</node>
```

Retrieves the simplified entry:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&osm_type=N&osm_id=244082315&accept-language=zh
```

This does not work

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&osm_type=N&osm_id=244082315&accept-language=zh-TW
```

How can I retrieve traditional Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but it seems like Nominatim doesn't know/support all language codes at the moment. However you can access [node 244082315](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/244082315) directly via the [OSM API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6).